# Image overlay on a slideshow puts the overlay on the next slide

Tags: html, css

This is what each slide looks like:

```css
.slideImage {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.slideOverlay {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slideImage:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.slideOverlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className="each-slide">
  <div className="slideImage" style={{ 'backgroundImage': `url(${slideImages[0]})`}}>
  </div>
  <div className="slideOverlay">
    <p>OverlayText</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's three slides. The image overlay text only appears on the 2nd slide and the 2nd slide doesn't fade out. Can someone tell me why that is?

Comment: Where is the image ? => please read here how to add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping the image is in that 2nd div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is .each-slide's position needed to be relative